# Is it possible to store answers in a database as integers?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Before you read on I just want to make something perfectly clear, Im not looking for someone to code this for me, I just need to know whether it would be possible for me to do this, as I don't have that long to spend on this part of the task, and I thought it'd be best to ask the experts/guys on Stackoverflow.

So my question is: 
I have a number of questionnaires, which will be completed by participants, since the answers are strings, I was wondering whether it would be possible to store these answers as integers, for example, you'd have:

1 ="Never True" 2="Rarely True" 3="Sometime true" 4="Often True" 5="Very Often True". I want to store only the numbers, I was just wondering whether that would be possible.

Thank You.

**Finished**

I think before I had worded the question quite badly, my bad. However, I did manage to complete that part, I stored the values in the database, which I assigned to each of the answers. Also as @octern had mentioned to create a code, this was also very handy, so thank you.

I appreciate all the responses, and your time for dealing with this question.

Comment: Have you tried googling for "mysql data types"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. If your participants are using an HTML form to submit their answers, just set the VALUE attribute of the form element to the numeric code for the answer, and that's what will go in your database.

Just make **very, very sure** that you create a codebook so you can figure out which number corresponds to which answer in the future! You don't want to rely on parsing the web page, which may have changed over time.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the advice :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store integers in a database. And obviously you can assign your own meaning to those integers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. Alternatively, You can create a table called "possible_answers" for example with id as the primary key and text as the question. The table that stores the answers to a question can now have a foreign key to the possible_answers table to make sure the integer saved is always valid.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways to store the values as integers in a relatively easy way to read and understand.

The simplest way is to store them as an ENUM because the value stored in the row is actually an index to the list of possibilities in the ENUM declaration. The problem with ENUMs is the list of possible answers must be known in advance, and the list needs to remain relatively static unless you like taking outages to change the table's structure each time you want to maintain that list.

The most flexible way is to create a table with an ID column (typically an auto_increment or serial of some sort) and the label used for that number. Then, the original table simply refers to the ID column in the "other" table. This is commonly referred to as a foreign key reference.

In MySQL, the performance of ENUMs versus foreign key references is nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly store integers in a database. Keep in mind that if you do this, you will need to "translate" those integers into the actual answers in your application, probably with a switch statement.